# Integración de OpenPay con PHP

Tags: php, openpay

Buen día.
Me encuentro implementando una pasarela de pago con OpenPay, he colocado el formulario de tarjeta para realizar los tokens como se menciona en la página y ahora me encuentro en la sección de crear cargo, el cual no entiendo como se implementa. Dejo el código que me dan. He sustituído los POST por datos y luego lo corro en mi servidor, pero no me genera ninguna respuesta en el ambiente SANDBOX. Me podrían asesorar como integrar esto?

```
$openpay = Openpay::getInstance('*****',
  '*****');

$customer = array(
     'name' => $_POST["name"],
     'last_name' => $_POST["last_name"],
     'phone_number' => $_POST["phone_number"],
     'email' => $_POST["email"],);

$chargeData = array(
    'method' => 'card',
    'source_id' => $_POST["token_id"],
    'amount' => $_POST["amount"], // formato númerico con hasta dos dígitos decimales. 
    'description' => $_POST["description"],
    'use_card_points' => $_POST["use_card_points"], // Opcional, si estamos usando puntos
    'device_session_id' => $_POST["deviceIdHiddenFieldName"],
    'customer' => $customer
    );

$charge = $openpay->charges->create($chargeData);
?>
```

Comment: ¿El log de apache no te muestra algun error o mensaje que ayude a detectar el inconveniente?

Comment: ¿Pudiste resolverlo? Si no, revisa la [documentación](https://www.openpay.mx/docs/api/?php#con-id-de-tarjeta-o-token), `$charge` te devuelve un objeto que debes analizar, por ejemplo: `if($charge->status == 'completed') { ... el pago se completó ... }`